# I need to remove double quotes from JSON for use in NSDictionary

Tags: php, iphone, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a JSON return that I'm trying to save into a NSDictionary, However, Since there are spaces in the data being returned, the Dictionary won't save this array because of the quote being included. Is there a way to parse the SBJSON to remove the double quotes prior to saving to the rowsArray?

```
  rowsArray: {
 Rows =     (
            {
        Children =             (
                            {
                Title = Chevy;
            },
                            {
                Title = "Red Color";
            },
                            {
                Title = "Pre - 1965";
            },
                            {
                Title = "White Walls";
            },           
        );
        Title = Chevy;
    },
```

Here is the code
        //JSON NSURL REQUEST for rowsArray

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.**.php"];
    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url ]


    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    rowsArray= [json objectWithString:jsonreturn error:&error];

NSLog(@"rowsArray: %@",rowsArray);


//SAVING rowsArray as "FollowingArray.plist"

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FollowingArray.plist"];


    [rowsArray writeToFile:path2 atomically:NO];


    [jsonreturn release];
    [json release];
```

This works Great and saves if the string where  Chevy is, but if the double quotes are in there the .plist won't save

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to remove all the quotes would be to use:

`-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:]`

like so:

```
NSString *cleanedString=[jsonreturn stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"" withString:@""];
```

the "/" is the escape character for the quotes.